# WPF OnPropertyChanged - notify another VM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have small application with 2 UserControls. First contains login form and second UserControl displayed authenticated user. But in second user control I cannot displayed AuthenticatedUser. I viewmodel is value of AuthenticatedUser but in xaml not.
Here is my code:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<local:Login/>
<local:Test/>
```

**Login.xaml**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Username, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
<Button Content="LOGIN" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
AFTER LOGIN BUTTON CLICK HERE IS VALUE
<TextBlock Text="{Binding AuthenticatedUser}"/>
```

**LoginVM.cs**

```
class LoginVM : BaseVm
{
    private string _username;
    public string Username
    {
        get => _username;
        set
        {
            _username = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Username));
        }
    }

    public Command LoginCommand { get; }

    public LoginVM()
    {
        LoginCommand = new Command(x =>
        {
            var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as Principal;
            principal.Identity = new Identity(Username);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AuthenticatedUser));
        });
    }
}
```

**BaseVM**

```
class BaseVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string AuthenticatedUser => (Thread.CurrentPrincipal as Principal).Identity.Name;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**Test.xaml**

```
 <TextBlock Text="USER: "/>

 AFTER LOGIN BUTTON CLICK HERE IS NOT VALUE
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding AuthenticatedUser}"/>
```

**TestVm.cs**

```
class TestVm : BaseVm
{
}
```

How to notify other userControls? Thanks for advices

Comment: You don't need a ViewModel per UseControl, it's totally sufficient to create one ViewModel for your MainWindow and let both UserControls bind on that

Comment: Yes, in this simple example. But I would like to check when user is authenticated in whole application. I can not have only one ViewModel. I need notify many ViewModels that AuthenticatedUser is changed

Comment: Subscribe the other VM and notify the property change. Or create and Event Aggregator, send the property change event from 1 VM and multiple VMs can handle that event.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it please?

Comment: Refer this link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23314.using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models.aspx